# Problem loading R own created libraries in Java/JRI code

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I created my own new R library (called "Media"). There is no problem when I try to load it with RGui, and I can call the functions defined in the new package.  This is how I load it:

```
   > library(Media)
```

But, I'm also trying to call that functions from [Java/JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) code, and when I load the new R package, Java doesn't seem to find the pacakge, throwing the message "Error in library(Media) : object 'Media' not found"

This is my current code using JRI:

```
    REXP rexpSetFolder = re.eval("setwd('C:/Users/Albert/Documents')");
    REXP rexpFolder = re.eval("getwd()");
    System.out.println(rexpFolder.asString());

    REXP rexpLoad = re.eval("library(Media)"); // fails
```

It also fails without the 'setwd' command, and simple calls to existing R functions work fine.  I'm using R 2.10 and the latest JRI 0.5-0 under Windows.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

**Edit:**

The parameter `lib.loc` seems to work, at least this sentence does not return an error:

```
library("Media", lib.loc = "c:/Users/Albert/Documents")
```

But after that, calling a function in the package with `re.eval("myfunction()");` still fails, as the function is not properly found.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the library path - see `?.libPaths` in R, you simply want to add your private library to the path. The GUI does that for you, but if you are outside it doesn't happen. For example:

```
 re.eval(".libPaths('c:/users/foo/Documents/R')");
```

Then load your package.

Comment: This has been useful for me. But I had to use: `re.eval(".libPaths('c:/users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/3.2')");`, in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the library properly first?  You might want to try using the `lib.loc` parameter.

```
library("Media", lib.loc = "c:/Users/Albert/Documents")
```

Comment: I'll try it, but the strange thing is that I can execute the same code without problems directly in RGui.  Thank you.

Comment: The sentence seems to work with the argument "lib.loc" but, after that, calling a function in the package called "media" with re.eval("media( t )"); still fails, with a message that says that it was not able to find "media" function...

Answer (score 1):

My work-around was to copy the package from my personal library (%USERPROFILE%\Documents\R) to the global library (%R_HOME%\library).

It's not the best because this requires Administrator privileges which not all users will have...

Comment: Sadly I didn't find a solution (yours seems a nice workaround).  I finally inlined the functions in a re.eval call, instead of making them part of a library (as I was trying to do).