# How I can load add-on R libraries into JRI and execute from Java?

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I am working with a Java and I need to use an add-on R library and use the functions within that library. I tried the answers provided in the following questions

[How I can load a R script into JRI and execute from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037411/how-i-can-load-a-r-script-into-jri-and-execute-from-java)

[Problem loading R own created libraries in Java/JRI code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477398/problem-loading-r-own-created-libraries-in-java-jri-code)

but I still get a NullPointerException. Can anyone point out the error. Thankyou

Here is the code which I am using:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RVector;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class RConnect { 

public void processFiles(String[] spectrumData)
{
    // new R-engine
    Rengine re=new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
    if (!re.waitForR())
    {
        System.out.println ("Unable to load R");
        return;
    }
    else
        System.out.println ("Connected to R");

    REXP rexpSetFolder = re.eval("setwd('/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0')");
    REXP rexpFolder = re.eval("getwd()");
    System.out.println(rexpFolder.asString());

    REXP rexpLoad = re.eval("library(PROcess)");
    RVector f1 = (re.eval("read.files(spectrumData)").asVector());
    System.out.println(f1);

    re.end();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to look for the R package "PROcess" you just mentioned, but i didn't find it, so i cant test your code, but generally add in packages work perfect in JRI, here is an example (using packages "forecast" and "plyr"):

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RVector;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
/**
 *
 * @author yschellekens
 */
public class StackOverfolw {
    private static double[] foreCast;
    private static int i;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // new R-engine
    Rengine re=new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
    if (!re.waitForR())
    {
        System.out.println ("Unable to load R");
        return;
    }
    else
        System.out.println ("Connected to R");

    re.eval("load(file='C:/Users/yschellekens.INTRANET/Desktop/java projects/count_basic.Rda')  ", false);
        re.eval("library(plyr)");   
        re.eval("library(forecast)");
        re.eval("count_basic<-arrange(count_basic,TKDate)");
        re.eval("ts1<-ts(count_basic$click_count,frequency=7)");         
        re.eval("value<-stl(x=ts1,s.window=7)");
        re.eval("fit <- auto.arima(ts1)");
        re.eval("fit2<-forecast(fit,h=30)");
        re.eval("value3<-as.numeric(fit2$mean)");
        REXP testYvalue = re.eval("c(as.numeric(fit2$fitted),as.numeric(fit2$mean))");
        foreCast=testYvalue.asDoubleArray();


         for (i = 0; i < 10  ; i++) {
             System.out.println(foreCast[i]);;} 
    re.end();
}
    }
```

1. Now look at the console:

   run:
   Connected to R
   524.0
   597.0
   530.0
   440.0
   406.0
   435.0
   479.0
   523.0
   580.0
   574.0
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

My guess i that you downloaded the package "PROcess" (which i couldn't find) on a earlier version of R (not 3.0), if that is the case, just reload the package into your R 3.0 folder.

Comment: I tried to do a similar thing and it throws NPE. I have created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660138/rengine-eval-returns-null) for it, could you please take a look?